# Looking for items in dict

Tags: python

I'm having an issue with dict and list:
I have a function that ask user for an input, can be multiple items. The function allows only items that I have in a dict
Once I get the input, I need to look for the value of each key (item)
I'm trying to extract each element of the list and have multiple variables (I tried with tuple)
but when I try to look for the value of each key with .get() the output is none

```
def main():
    i = tuple(user_item())
        *#use tuple to avoid TypeError unhashable list*
    print(i)
        *#I use the print statement here to help debugging
        #the output is: ('Name_item', )
        #which means that it founds the item in my user_item function*
    print(items.get(i))
        *#output is none, also tried:* print(items.get("i"))  = output None

def user_item():
    order = []
    while True:
        try:
            i = input("Item: ").title()
            if i in items:
                order.append(i)
                continue
        except EOFError:
            return order
main()
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete and won't run. Is this the actual code you are running? Also, see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: `print(items.get(i))` You haven't defined `items` anywhere...

Comment: items is the name of the dictionary, I didn't copy paste it in the post but it is just on top of my main function

Comment: the programme run without problems, prompt for items until the exception (ctrl D) and then the first print actually print all the items in this form('item', 'item', 'item', ) but then output none for the values of the keys (items name)

Comment: also if I replace I in print(items.get(i)) by the actual name of the item it prints the value of the key

Comment: This code won't run in Python, hence the downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `i` in `main()` is actually a tuple not a string. So, when you do `items.get(i)` it returns `None` as the dict has no tuple as keys but strings! Try instead:

```py
for key in i:
  print(items.get(key))
```

Also there is no need to do `i = tuple(user_item())`: since `user_item()` returns a list, you can just have `i = user_item()`. This with the previous code should fix also the error "TypeError unhashable list".

Comment: Morning, thank you ! That line did it. I was looking everywhere on google on how to extract multiple variable from a list whiteout knowing in advance how many variables I will receive from the input and that's why I used tuple. have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip, just like you asked:

So you have a tuple of strings, that's alright. But you're using the get() method of a dictionary. The get() method accepts it but returns None, because it didn't find any keys that match your tuple. Tuples can be dictionary entries on their own, that's why it doesn't throw an exception, since it searched the keys for it and didn't find one - as a whole, not its individual elements. I suspect what you want to do is search for every individual item of the tuple inside your dictionary - you'll have to do this differently.

Here's a solution to your problem in case you need it:

> # use a simple for loop, or even better/faster - an itemgetter 
>  # remember that you'll still get key errors when trying to access a non-existing key
>
> ```
> from operator import itemgetter
> values = itemgetter(*i)(items)
> print(values)
> ```

Also, as a general good practice - try to parametrize your functions, if you're accessing the items dictionary, pass it directly as an argument of the function to avoid ambiguity, e.g.
`def user_item(items):`

Though I'd suggest not calling your dictionary "items", because it'll lead to confusion later on, since dictionary items are its key-value pairs, and the word is used as a method name to access them e.g.
`my_dict.items()`

Comment: Hey! Thank for your advices, I'm still fighting with understanding concepts and syntax of the language but I will push myself to write more readable and understandable code

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually runs [code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLn4J.png)

You are only appending to order `if i in items` and thats what you get, maybe your dict keys are not capitalized as "i" is.

Comment: all items in the dict are titled, hence the .title() in the get_items function